# How do I validate this select option if not selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to validate this select option but it never worked . I've added the class = 'required' and added the rule too in jquery validation , but it did not work either.

I need a solution to this problem

mycode :

```
    <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2"><font size="2" color="white">Jenis Kelamin</font></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select class="form-control required" name="jk" id="gender" required/>
<option>Pilih</option>
<option value="Laki-Laki">Laki - Laki</option>
<option value="Perempuan">Perempuan</option>
</select>
</div>
&nbsp;
</div>
```

```js
// add the rule here
 $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg !== value;
 }, "Value must not equal arg.");

 // configure your validation
 $("gender").validate({
  rules: {
   jk: { valueNotEquals: "default" }
  },
  messages: {
   jk: { valueNotEquals: "Please select an item!" }
  }  
 });
```

Comment: To validate input with html you need a form. You need to add the form element around your entire code and add a submit button which will validate it when you click submit.

Comment: Where is the form and submit button?

Comment: Are you using jquery validation plugin?

Comment: I've done that.

Comment: @RyukLee code to long :( .

Comment: @Bee yeah i edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a disabled and selected `option` to your `select` for the `required` to work properly, forcing the user to explicitly select one option first:

```html
<form>
  <select class="form-control required" name="jk" id="gender" required>
    <option disabled selected></option>
    <option>Pilih</option>
    <option value="Laki-Laki">Laki - Laki</option>
    <option value="Perempuan">Perempuan</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
<option>Pilih</option>
```

To:

```
<option value="">Pilih</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<select class="form-control required" name="jk" id="gender" required >
<option disabled selected></option>
<option value="Pilih">Pilih</option>
<option value="Laki-Laki">Laki - Laki</option>
<option value="Perempuan">Perempuan</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question :)